# error: [astro preview] adapter does not have previewentrypoint

Tags: javascript, html, preview, astrojs

I've been making a website with astro (https://astro.build) and after some time, while running `astro preview` it errors. Here's my `astro.config.mjs` code:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import vercel from '@astrojs/vercel/serverless';
import serviceWorker from 'astrojs-service-worker';

export default defineConfig({
    trailingSlash: 'ignore',
    output: 'server',
    adapter: vercel(),
    integrations: [serviceWorker()],
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't preview the build of SSR adapters with `astro preview`, except the node adapter.

I'm quoting the [docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/cli-reference/#astro-preview)

> Since Astro 1.5.0, astro preview also works for SSR builds if you use an adapter that supports it. Currently, only the Node adapter supports astro preview.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. I adapt the scripts in the `package.json` file:

```js
//...
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx astro build ./",
  "build:node": "npx astro build ./ --node",
  "preview": "npx astro preview --node",
//...
```

2. I adapt the configuration in the `astro.config.mjs` file:

```js
//...
import node from "@astrojs/node";
import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless";
    
let adapter = vercel();
    
if (process.argv[3] === "--node" || process.argv[4] === "--node") {
  adapter = node({ mode: "standalone" });
}
    
/**
 * Astro.js configuration.
 * @see https://astro.build/config
*/
export default defineConfig({
  output: "server",
  adapter: adapter,
//...
```

3. Use the command `npm run build:node` to build locally and `npm run preview`. Vercel uses the `npm run build` command and employs its adapter.

You can see the example used in my [repository](https://github.com/sergio-ridaura/astro_kickstart)